# Why do Sass variable arguments throw an error?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using [Sass Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap) and getting an error where it uses a [variable argument](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments).

The only solution I see from searching for my problem is to make sure I'm on SASS 3.2.x. I was on 3.3.0.alpha.101, but uninstalled and reinstalled 3.2.8, but I'm still getting the error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...-shadow($shadow": expected ")", was "...) {"
```

The code that's throwing the error:

```
@mixin box-shadow($shadow...) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadow;
     -moz-box-shadow: $shadow;
          box-shadow: $shadow;
}
```

I should also mention that I'm using LiveReload 2.3.8.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your console?  If that doesn't work, a reboot may be necessary.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing my question to include that I'm using LiveReload, I thought to try using good-ol'-fashioned `sass-watch` and there wasn't a problem.

I've reported this as a bug to LiveReload…

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help your situation, but for anyone else, check your version of Sass. The variable arguments feature was introduced in Sass 3.2.

http://chriseppstein.github.io/blog/2012/08/23/sass-3-2-is-released/

Comment: You obviously didn't read the question. I stated the 3.2 possibility.

Comment: Wow, speaking of "sass" :-)